# How to search all child and sub-child elements? Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I want to create a line of code that looks for a specific string of text in all child and sub-child elements of an already defined element. Below is a sample web page code to illustrate (forgive me if the html and css are bad):

```
<div class="className">
  <div>TEXT 01</div>
  <div>TEXT 02</div>
  <div>
    <div>TEXT 03</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
    <div>TEXT 04</div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want Selenium to analyze all text inside of the main div and return that text, including TEXT 01, TEXT 02, TEXT 03, TEXT 04. Here's what I have so far:

```
parent_element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('className')
test = parent_element.find_element_by_xpath('.//*').text
print(test)
```

Unfortunately, this is not working to return all of the text. Any ideas? THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
test=[x.text for x in parent.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[contains(.,'TEXT')]")
```

or use .//* for non divs.

To get all child text who contains a certain text. Use find_elements and contains.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not working. The ".//" seems like it is not crawling everything underneath parent element for text.

Comment: Try it out now.